How to traverse the nodes in an Abstract Syntax Tree for a set of conditions?
How to traverse CEL AST and build condition stack in order?
I'm using celparser.py from the cel-python library to parse CEL expressions and generate an AST. After parsing, I need to traverse the AST and build a condition stack with the innermost condition at the top.
For example, given this CEL expression:
(a.name == 'Jon' && (c.role == 'lead' || c.region == 'US')) ? b.salary : c.bonus

I expect the stack to look like this:
c.role == 'lead'
c.region == 'US'
c.role == 'lead' || c.region == 'US'
a.name == 'Jon' && (c.role == 'lead' || c.region == 'US')

What’s the best way to achieve this traversal and stack-building from the AST? Any help would be appreciated!
